# На какие сайты применить HTML+PHP?

Tags: html, cms, php

Добрый день, скажите пожалуйста, насколько на сегодняшний день актуальны сайты на HTML+PHP? Есть ли пример сайта? Я вот хочу сделать, допустим, туристический сайт, проще ведь на CMS делать, не так ли? В каких случаях лучше сделать на  HTML+PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас специфическая логика "сайта", которая не представлена модулями или нужна высокая производительность, то следует писать код самостоятельно. Но не всегда нужно писать весь "сайт" с нуля. В некоторых случаях достаточно написать подключаемый модуль/плагин к CMS.
Кстати - практически все CMS написаны на HTML+JS+PHP

Comment: спасибо, именно это я хотела услышать)

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемая Аня! 
Подавляющее большинство сайтов сделано именно на "HTML+PHP". Мало того. CMS(Content Management System - система управления контентом) тоже чаще всего делаются именно на PHP.
Так что актуальности этот язык не потерял и ныне.

Другое дело, создавать ли сайт с нуля или использовать готовое решение(что, видимо, и подразумевалось в вопросе) - решение для частного случая.
Если в программировании вы не очень хорошо разбираетесь, а запускать надо быстро, стоит начать с какой-то готовой CMS. 
В дальнейшем, ее можно будет переписать, если возникнет необходимость.
В общем случае, универсальные системы более требовательные к ресурсам, чем заточенные под конкретные задачи.

Comment: вы меня правильно понимаете, я просто растерялась и не могу понять,неужели так важно с 0 создавать если можно что-то переделать, ведь все итак пишется на HTML и пхп и т.д.
Ребята, спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Нет, создавать с 0 не обязательно. Вы всегда можете выбрать компромисс между временем разработки и ресурсоемкостью:  

 1. Можно вообще писать сайт на C или каком-нибудь еще более низкоуровневом языке. Изврат. Понимаю. Двигаемся дальше:
 2. чистый PHP.
 3. PHP+какой-нибудь фреймворк.
 4. Готовая CMS. Написание модулей
 5. Готовая CMS. As IS.  
перечисленно не все. Но более-менее значимые точки.

Comment: эхх, как много я еще не знаю. Будем делать и учить

Comment: Все зависит от ваших потребностей. При необходимости я думаю узнается все )

Answer (score 1):

Понимаете в чем речь, CMS это не что-то волшебное, таинственное и магическое (хотя в некоторых cms магии через край, ну да не об этом хотел сказать) так вот, о чем это я... А! CMS ведь тоже на чем то написаны. И осмелюсь предположить что написаны на php. Поэтому вопрос сводится к -

**"Использовать CMS или писать всё с нуля для создания сайтов ?"**

Пожалуй используйте CMS, ибо что бы написать что-то стоящее вам понадобится очень много времени, сил и конечно же знаний. Используя CMS ваша жизнь упростится в создании сайтов.

Comment: блин, только что ни одного ответа не было, пока писал ... :)

Comment: Спасибо)
Вот и ответили на мои вопросы, а я так боялась чтобы не загнобили)

Comment: чем больше Ваших ответов- тем мне понятнее))